# Nodejs / React Elastic Beanstalk: Changes to codebase not displaying on the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node/react app running on Elastic Beanstalk. When I run eb deploy from my terminal, I do not get any errors.

[Terminal output after running eb deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKRHv.png)

There are no errors in my Elastic Beanstalk dashboard either.

However, none of my changes made to the app are actually displaying on the frontend. The code that is deployed is up to date - yet client-side, nothing will update.

Anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: Have you checked the logs in Cloudwatch for that instance to see what's happening on the instance?

Comment: also have you pushed the code changes to Github or wherever you are storing your code?

Comment: Access the environment of your application and go logs and ask the last 100 lines to see what is happening deploy often for being successful but sometimes the error only appears during use.

Comment: There is nothing in Cloudwatch to suggest issues and yes, my github is up to date. In the last 100 lines of my logs, I see the following error: Error: list EADDRINUSE ::: 8081

Comment: I also see this error in my nginx logs: 2019/01/18 18:06:51 [error] 4419 # 0: * 2 connect () failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.56.20, server:, request: "GET /.git / objects / 5f /? C = D; O = D HTTP / 1.1 ", upstream:" http://127.0.0.1:8081/.git/objects/5f/?C=D;O=D ", host: "52.22.143.110", referrer: "http://52.22.143.110/.git/objects/5f/?C=D;O=A"

Comment: If the code is deployed properly, then it could be a service worker or caching issue. I would suggest viewing the page in a private window, your changes may show up. Or you can unregister the service worker. But it may be a deeper issue looking at your comments.

Comment: I have already tried a private window, so it not a cacheing issue. Not sure how to troubleshoot service workers.